Load low resolution version of polygon in lower zoom level, in leaflet
Leaflet uses the principle of loading map tiles according to the zoom level, that is, the resolution of the map image depends on the zoom level. Can we apply the same principle to a polygon?
My website main page loads a broad map with several high-resolution polygons, but they take a lot of time to load (around 7 MB, ~2s, which is a lot for a main page). Is there a way to load only a low resolution version of the polygons, and load higher resolution versions according to zoom level, exactly as it's done with the raster tiles?


Cross-post of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/480608/load-only-low-resolution-of-polygons-in-leaflet

Someone recommended me to use Leaflet.VectorGrid plugin but I still don't get how to reduce the data sent from the server to the browser.
Run this snippet:


var map = L.map('map');

var cartodbAttribution = '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>';

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: cartodbAttribution,
  opacity: 1
}).addTo(map);

fetch('https://geoapi.pt/distritos?json=1').then(r => r.json()).then(districts => {
  const geoJsonFeatureCollection = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: districts.filter(d => d.geojson).map(d => d.geojson)
  }
  
  L.vectorGrid.slicer( geoJsonFeatureCollection, {
  rendererFactory: L.svg.tile
  }).addTo(map)
})

map.setView({ lat: 39.230022343470175, lng: -8.396909834716356 }, 5);
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.vectorgrid@1.2.0"></script>

<div id="map"></div>



Now with different package leaflet-geojson-vt, but the problem persists. Run the snippet:


var map = L.map('map');

var cartodbAttribution = '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>';

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: cartodbAttribution,
  opacity: 1
}).addTo(map);

fetch('https://geoapi.pt/distritos?json=1').then(r => r.json()).then(districts => {
  const geoJsonFeatureCollection = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: districts.filter(d => d.geojson).map(d => d.geojson)
  }
  
  var options = {
    maxZoom: 16,
    tolerance: 3,
    debug: 0,
    style: {
      fillColor: "#1EB300",
      color: "#F2FF00",
    }
  }
  L.geoJson.vt(geoJsonFeatureCollection, options).addTo(map)
})

map.setView({ lat: 39.230022343470175, lng: -8.396909834716356 }, 5);
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/geojson-vt@3.2.0/geojson-vt.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-geojson-vt@1.1.0/src/leaflet-geojson-vt.min.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>



